# Simulating the Impact of Bicycling on Hip Joint Cartilage

Tags: finite-element-method, simulation, abaqus, biomechanics

Sorry if this question comes off as obvious. I have more of a biology/clinical research background, and I have almost 0 experience with FEA.

I have 50 sequential data points of the hip joint angles of a person riding a bicycle, stored as a CSV. These 50 points define 1 full cycle of the joint. I also have 3D models with the bones and ligaments of the hip segmented from a scan. Is it possible, using the joint angles from CSV file, to use ABAQUS (or any other FEA software) to solve for the stress on the ligaments during 1 cycle/period?

Thank you! I appreciate your time.

Comment: Not unless you know the forces.

Comment: So if I were to get the forces at each frame, I should be able to do this?

Comment: Yes, with all sorts of provisoes.